# Space between items in List of Figures/Tables within a chapter

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to add some tiny space between items within a chapter in the List of Figures/Tables. It should be compatible with `\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{Xpt}` I'm using for ToC.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}


\begin{document}

\listoftables
\listoffigures

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{100pt}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{a}
\section{1}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure1} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure2} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure3} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure1} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure2} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure3} \end{figure}

\chapter{b}
\section{1}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure4} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure5} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure6} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure4} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure5} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure6} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want 100pt of vertical separation bettwen chapter entreies in the LoF, LoT and some additional spacing between figure/table entries within each chapter?

Comment: Only in the LoF/LoT within a chapter (it shouldn't affect the vertical separation between blocks of F/T for a particular chapter). And not necessarily 100pt - I mentioned that just in case that the solution would contradict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redefine `\cftfigafterpnum`, `\cfttabafterpnum` to add the desired amount of space between entries within each chapter; in my example I used `5pt`, just for illustration, but use any other desired length:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{100pt}
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip5pt\par}
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip5pt\par}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\listoffigures
\tableofcontents

\chapter{a}
\section{1}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure1} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure2} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure3} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure1} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure2} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure3} \end{figure}

\chapter{b}
\section{1}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure4} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure5} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Performance at peak F-measure6} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure4} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure5} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{Performance at peak G-measure6} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

An image of the LoT:

[image]

An image of the LoF:

[image]

By the way, using just `[h]` as the float placement specification could be too restrictive.

Comment: Instead of renewing the command, to adjust spacing between figure and tab items, you can use `\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{16pt}` and `\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{16pt}` respectively. Change `16pt` value to your preference.